# Connect to socket.io(nodejs) via PHP

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, socket.io-1.0

I had a need to connect to websocket via php, send data and immediately disconnect. No need to wait for a response from the socket. I used [elefant.io](http://elephant.io/) but after updating the library does not work. Please tell me how to connect to websocket via PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also encountered this problem. Learned a lot of structure websocket requests. I wrote a library for yourself, you can use it.[PHP SocketIO Client](https://github.com/psinetron/PHP_SocketIO_Client).

You need simple socket connect to nodejs, compose in this message format.`42["message", "your message"]`' To encode to hybi10 (or hybi13) and send to websocket

Comment: Also, you can download any websoket library, but edit and put something like $header .= "GET /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1\r\n"; to socket.io server library work. Spent 2 hours trying to understand

Answer (score -3):

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );

var express = require( 'express' );

var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();

var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {

console.log( "New client !" );
```

Comment: Please format your post and add some explanation to what the code does