# Compose message 42["message", "your message"]' to encode to hybi10 (or hybi13) and send to websocket

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

[Here is almost complete SOLUTION on stackoverflow to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948669/connect-to-socket-ionodejs-via-php)

Problem is communication with my node JS server via PHP. I can't understand one detail in solution above:

> compose message 42["message", "your message"]' to encode to hybi10 (or
>   hybi13) and send to websocket

What does that mean? My node js server got "command" new message like this

```
  socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
  });
```

Code from solution im using is:

```
$socketio = new SocketIO();
if ($socketio->send('localhost', 8080, 'message')){
    echo 'we sent the message and disconnected';
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, we have a mistake :\'(';
}
```

This code only connects to my server, but how to send "new message" message in correct format? Can't understand this 42["message", "your message"]'

Comment: Result is in Array message is Key & Your Message is it's value.

Comment: i tried $arr = array('new message', 'myrealmessage');
$socketio = new SocketIO();
if ($socketio->send('localhost', 8080, $arr)){... but its not working :/

Answer (score 2):

this is for php client side

```
$socketio->send('localhost', 8080, 'add new message', 'this is my message');
```

this is for server side

```
// Socket receive "add new message" command    
socket.on('add new message', function (messageText) {
    // print message
    console.log(messageText);

    // Broadcast to all clients.
    socket.broadcast.emit('add new message', {
        username: socket.username,
        message: messageText
    });
});
```